# How to download to `GitHub Desktop`

Tags: macos, git

I have downloaded and installed `GitHub Desktop` to my Mac and it shows a couple of my projects.

Unfortunately I seem to be unable to use it to download anything.

The most recent try I went to https://github.com/jhobro/magpi_parallel2
There is a `Clone or download` button, and pressing this opens a popup with 2 buttons  `Open in Desktop` and `Download ZIP`.

Clicking the `Open in Desktop` always takes me to a link and tries to download a new copy of `GitHub Desktop`, despite the fact I already have the latest.

After trying every option I usually give up and just `Download ZIP`.

Can anyone explain if `GitHub Desktop` CAN be used to download, and HOW to do so.

`/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A‌/Frameworks/LaunchSe‌rvices.framework/Ver‌sions/A/Support/lsre‌gister -dump | grep -B45 "github-mac:"` shows:-

```
                {
            CFBundleURLName = "SourceTree URL";
            CFBundleURLSchemes =             (
                sourcetree,
                "github-mac"
            );
        }
    );
    CFBundleVersion = "1.8.0.2";
    NSHumanReadableCopyright = "Copyright 2010-2013 Atlassian. All Rights Reserved.";
    NSMainNibFile = MainMenu;
    NSPrincipalClass = NSApplication;
    NSServices =     (
                {
            NSMenuItem =             {
                default = "Open in SourceTree";
            };
            NSMessage = openInSourceTree;
            NSRequiredContext =             {
                NSTextContent = FilePath;
            };
            NSSendTypes =             (
                NSFilenamesPboardType
            );
        }
    );
}
    library:       Contents/Library/
    schemesList:   github-mac, sourcetree
    activityTypes: pv-ce07118f141dd8, NOTIFICATION#:com.torusknot.SourceTreeNotMAS
    --------------------------------------------------------
    claim   id:            5412
        name:          Folders
        rank:          Default
        roles:         Viewer  
        flags:         doc-type  
        icon:          
        bindings:      'fold'
    --------------------------------------------------------
    claim   id:            5416
        name:          SourceTree URL
        rank:          Default
        roles:         Viewer  
        flags:         url-type  
        icon:          
        bindings:      sourcetree:, github-mac:
--
    );
    CFBundleExecutable = "GitHub Desktop";
    CFBundleIconFile = "AppIcon-Release";
    CFBundleIdentifier = "com.github.GitHub";
    CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion = "6.0";
    CFBundleName = "GitHub Desktop";
    CFBundlePackageType = APPL;
    CFBundleShortVersionString = "Deer Types";
    CFBundleSignature = "????";
    CFBundleSupportedPlatforms =     (
        MacOSX
    );
    CFBundleURLTypes =     (
                {
            CFBundleURLName = "com.github.GitHub";
            CFBundleURLSchemes =             (
                "github-mac"
            );
        }
    );
    CFBundleVersion = 222;
    NSAppleScriptEnabled = YES;
    NSHumanReadableCopyright = "Copyright \U00a9 2016 GitHub, Inc.";
    NSMainNibFile = MainMenu;
    NSPrincipalClass = GHApplication;
    NSSupportsAutomaticGraphicsSwitching = 1;
}
    library:       Contents/Library/
    schemesList:   github-mac
    activityTypes: NOTIFICATION#VEKTX9H2N7:com.github.GitHub, pv-fb2923e44f3b4b
    --------------------------------------------------------
    claim   id:            50176
        name:          Directory
        rank:          Default
        roles:         Viewer  
        flags:         doc-type  
        icon:          
        bindings:      'fold'
    --------------------------------------------------------
    claim   id:            50180
        name:          com.github.GitHub
        rank:          Default
        roles:         Viewer  
        flags:         url-type  
        icon:          
        bindings:      github-mac:
--
            LSTypeIsPackage = 0;
        }
    );
    CFBundleExecutable = GitHub;
    CFBundleIconFile = "AppIcon-Release";
    CFBundleIdentifier = "com.github.GitHub";
    CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion = "6.0";
    CFBundleName = GitHub;
    CFBundlePackageType = APPL;
    CFBundleShortVersionString = "Troll The Respawn Jeremy";
    CFBundleSignature = "????";
    CFBundleURLTypes =     (
                {
            CFBundleURLName = "com.github.GitHub";
            CFBundleURLSchemes =             (
                "github-mac"
            );
        }
    );
    CFBundleVersion = 204;
    NSAppleScriptEnabled = YES;
    NSHumanReadableCopyright = "Copyright \U00a9 2015 GitHub, Inc.";
    NSMainNibFile = MainMenu;
    NSPrincipalClass = GHApplication;
    NSSupportsAutomaticGraphicsSwitching = 1;
}
    library:       Contents/Library/
    library items: LoginItems/GitHub Conduit.app/
    schemesList:   github-mac
    activityTypes: NOTIFICATION#VEKTX9H2N7:com.github.GitHub, pv-fb2923e44f3b4b
    --------------------------------------------------------
    claim   id:            50184
        name:          Directory
        rank:          Default
        roles:         Viewer  
        flags:         doc-type  
        icon:          
        bindings:      'fold'
    --------------------------------------------------------
    claim   id:            50188
        name:          com.github.GitHub
        rank:          Default
        roles:         Viewer  
        flags:         url-type  
        icon:          
        bindings:      github-mac:
--
    );
    CFBundleExecutable = "GitHub Desktop";
    CFBundleIconFile = "AppIcon-Release";
    CFBundleIdentifier = "com.github.GitHub";
    CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion = "6.0";
    CFBundleName = "GitHub Desktop";
    CFBundlePackageType = APPL;
    CFBundleShortVersionString = "Beset by Computers";
    CFBundleSignature = "????";
    CFBundleSupportedPlatforms =     (
        MacOSX
    );
    CFBundleURLTypes =     (
                {
            CFBundleURLName = "com.github.GitHub";
            CFBundleURLSchemes =             (
                "github-mac"
            );
        }
    );
    CFBundleVersion = 220;
    NSAppleScriptEnabled = YES;
    NSHumanReadableCopyright = "Copyright \U00a9 2015 GitHub, Inc.";
    NSMainNibFile = MainMenu;
    NSPrincipalClass = GHApplication;
    NSSupportsAutomaticGraphicsSwitching = 1;
}
    library:       Contents/Library/
    schemesList:   github-mac
    activityTypes: NOTIFICATION#VEKTX9H2N7:com.github.GitHub, pv-fb2923e44f3b4b
    --------------------------------------------------------
    claim   id:            28000
        name:          Directory
        rank:          Default
        roles:         Viewer  
        flags:         doc-type  
        icon:          
        bindings:      'fold'
    --------------------------------------------------------
    claim   id:            28004
        name:          com.github.GitHub
        rank:          Default
        roles:         Viewer  
        flags:         url-type  
        icon:          
        bindings:      github-mac:
--
            LSTypeIsPackage = 0;
        }
    );
    CFBundleExecutable = GitHub;
    CFBundleIconFile = "AppIcon-Release";
    CFBundleIdentifier = "com.github.GitHub";
    CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion = "6.0";
    CFBundleName = GitHub;
    CFBundlePackageType = APPL;
    CFBundleShortVersionString = "Troll The Respawn Jeremy";
    CFBundleSignature = "????";
    CFBundleURLTypes =     (
                {
            CFBundleURLName = "com.github.GitHub";
            CFBundleURLSchemes =             (
                "github-mac"
            );
        }
    );
    CFBundleVersion = 204;
    NSAppleScriptEnabled = YES;
    NSHumanReadableCopyright = "Copyright \U00a9 2015 GitHub, Inc.";
    NSMainNibFile = MainMenu;
    NSPrincipalClass = GHApplication;
    NSSupportsAutomaticGraphicsSwitching = 1;
}
    library:       Contents/Library/
    library items: LoginItems/GitHub Conduit.app/
    schemesList:   github-mac
    activityTypes: NOTIFICATION#VEKTX9H2N7:com.github.GitHub, pv-fb2923e44f3b4b
    --------------------------------------------------------
    claim   id:            28008
        name:          Directory
        rank:          Default
        roles:         Viewer  
        flags:         doc-type  
        icon:          
        bindings:      'fold'
    --------------------------------------------------------
    claim   id:            28012
        name:          com.github.GitHub
        rank:          Default
        roles:         Viewer  
        flags:         url-type  
        icon:          
        bindings:      github-mac:
--
    );
    CFBundleExecutable = "GitHub Desktop";
    CFBundleIconFile = "AppIcon-Release";
    CFBundleIdentifier = "com.github.GitHub";
    CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion = "6.0";
    CFBundleName = "GitHub Desktop";
    CFBundlePackageType = APPL;
    CFBundleShortVersionString = "Beset by Computers";
    CFBundleSignature = "????";
    CFBundleSupportedPlatforms =     (
        MacOSX
    );
    CFBundleURLTypes =     (
                {
            CFBundleURLName = "com.github.GitHub";
            CFBundleURLSchemes =             (
                "github-mac"
            );
        }
    );
    CFBundleVersion = 220;
    NSAppleScriptEnabled = YES;
    NSHumanReadableCopyright = "Copyright \U00a9 2015 GitHub, Inc.";
    NSMainNibFile = MainMenu;
    NSPrincipalClass = GHApplication;
    NSSupportsAutomaticGraphicsSwitching = 1;
}
    library:       Contents/Library/
    schemesList:   github-mac
    activityTypes: NOTIFICATION#VEKTX9H2N7:com.github.GitHub, pv-fb2923e44f3b4b
    --------------------------------------------------------
    claim   id:            10516
        name:          Directory
        rank:          Default
        roles:         Viewer  
        flags:         doc-type  
        icon:          
        bindings:      'fold'
    --------------------------------------------------------
    claim   id:            10520
        name:          com.github.GitHub
        rank:          Default
        roles:         Viewer  
        flags:         url-type  
        icon:          
        bindings:      github-mac:
--
            LSTypeIsPackage = 0;
        }
    );
    CFBundleExecutable = GitHub;
    CFBundleIconFile = "AppIcon-Release";
    CFBundleIdentifier = "com.github.GitHub";
    CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion = "6.0";
    CFBundleName = GitHub;
    CFBundlePackageType = APPL;
    CFBundleShortVersionString = "Troll The Respawn Jeremy";
    CFBundleSignature = "????";
    CFBundleURLTypes =     (
                {
            CFBundleURLName = "com.github.GitHub";
            CFBundleURLSchemes =             (
                "github-mac"
            );
        }
    );
    CFBundleVersion = 204;
    NSAppleScriptEnabled = YES;
    NSHumanReadableCopyright = "Copyright \U00a9 2015 GitHub, Inc.";
    NSMainNibFile = MainMenu;
    NSPrincipalClass = GHApplication;
    NSSupportsAutomaticGraphicsSwitching = 1;
}
    library:       Contents/Library/
    library items: LoginItems/GitHub Conduit.app/
    schemesList:   github-mac
    activityTypes: NOTIFICATION#VEKTX9H2N7:com.github.GitHub, pv-fb2923e44f3b4b
    --------------------------------------------------------
    claim   id:            10524
        name:          Directory
        rank:          Default
        roles:         Viewer  
        flags:         doc-type  
        icon:          
        bindings:      'fold'
    --------------------------------------------------------
    claim   id:            10528
        name:          com.github.GitHub
        rank:          Default
        roles:         Viewer  
        flags:         url-type  
        icon:          
        bindings:      github-mac:
--
                {
            CFBundleURLName = "SourceTree URL";
            CFBundleURLSchemes =             (
                sourcetree,
                "github-mac"
            );
        }
    );
    CFBundleVersion = "1.8.0.2";
    NSHumanReadableCopyright = "Copyright 2010-2013 Atlassian. All Rights Reserved.";
    NSMainNibFile = MainMenu;
    NSPrincipalClass = NSApplication;
    NSServices =     (
                {
            NSMenuItem =             {
                default = "Open in SourceTree";
            };
            NSMessage = openInSourceTree;
            NSRequiredContext =             {
                NSTextContent = FilePath;
            };
            NSSendTypes =             (
                NSFilenamesPboardType
            );
        }
    );
}
    library:       Contents/Library/
    schemesList:   github-mac, sourcetree
    activityTypes: pv-ce07118f141dd8, NOTIFICATION#:com.torusknot.SourceTreeNotMAS
    --------------------------------------------------------
    claim   id:            10684
        name:          Folders
        rank:          Default
        roles:         Viewer  
        flags:         doc-type  
        icon:          
        bindings:      'fold'
    --------------------------------------------------------
    claim   id:            10688
        name:          SourceTree URL
        rank:          Default
        roles:         Viewer  
        flags:         url-type  
        icon:          
        bindings:      sourcetree:, github-mac:
--
                {
            CFBundleURLName = "SourceTree URL";
            CFBundleURLSchemes =             (
                sourcetree,
                "github-mac"
            );
        }
    );
    CFBundleVersion = "1.8.0.2";
    NSHumanReadableCopyright = "Copyright 2010-2013 Atlassian. All Rights Reserved.";
    NSMainNibFile = MainMenu;
    NSPrincipalClass = NSApplication;
    NSServices =     (
                {
            NSMenuItem =             {
                default = "Open in SourceTree";
            };
            NSMessage = openInSourceTree;
            NSRequiredContext =             {
                NSTextContent = FilePath;
            };
            NSSendTypes =             (
                NSFilenamesPboardType
            );
        }
    );
}
    library:       Contents/Library/
    schemesList:   github-mac, sourcetree
    activityTypes: pv-ce07118f141dd8, NOTIFICATION#:com.torusknot.SourceTreeNotMAS
    --------------------------------------------------------
    claim   id:            29156
        name:          Folders
        rank:          Default
        roles:         Viewer  
        flags:         doc-type  
        icon:          
        bindings:      'fold'
    --------------------------------------------------------
    claim   id:            29160
        name:          SourceTree URL
        rank:          Default
        roles:         Viewer  
        flags:         url-type  
        icon:          
        bindings:      sourcetree:, github-mac:
--
    );
    CFBundleExecutable = "GitHub Desktop";
    CFBundleIconFile = "AppIcon-Release";
    CFBundleIdentifier = "com.github.GitHub";
    CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion = "6.0";
    CFBundleName = "GitHub Desktop";
    CFBundlePackageType = APPL;
    CFBundleShortVersionString = "Beset by Computers";
    CFBundleSignature = "????";
    CFBundleSupportedPlatforms =     (
        MacOSX
    );
    CFBundleURLTypes =     (
                {
            CFBundleURLName = "com.github.GitHub";
            CFBundleURLSchemes =             (
                "github-mac"
            );
        }
    );
    CFBundleVersion = 220;
    NSAppleScriptEnabled = YES;
    NSHumanReadableCopyright = "Copyright \U00a9 2015 GitHub, Inc.";
    NSMainNibFile = MainMenu;
    NSPrincipalClass = GHApplication;
    NSSupportsAutomaticGraphicsSwitching = 1;
}
    library:       Contents/Library/
    schemesList:   github-mac
    activityTypes: NOTIFICATION#VEKTX9H2N7:com.github.GitHub, pv-fb2923e44f3b4b
    --------------------------------------------------------
    claim   id:            11932
        name:          Directory
        rank:          Default
        roles:         Viewer  
        flags:         doc-type  
        icon:          
        bindings:      'fold'
    --------------------------------------------------------
    claim   id:            11936
        name:          com.github.GitHub
        rank:          Default
        roles:         Viewer  
        flags:         url-type  
        icon:          
        bindings:      github-mac:
--
            LSTypeIsPackage = 0;
        }
    );
    CFBundleExecutable = GitHub;
    CFBundleIconFile = "AppIcon-Release";
    CFBundleIdentifier = "com.github.GitHub";
    CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion = "6.0";
    CFBundleName = GitHub;
    CFBundlePackageType = APPL;
    CFBundleShortVersionString = "Troll The Respawn Jeremy";
    CFBundleSignature = "????";
    CFBundleURLTypes =     (
                {
            CFBundleURLName = "com.github.GitHub";
            CFBundleURLSchemes =             (
                "github-mac"
            );
        }
    );
    CFBundleVersion = 204;
    NSAppleScriptEnabled = YES;
    NSHumanReadableCopyright = "Copyright \U00a9 2015 GitHub, Inc.";
    NSMainNibFile = MainMenu;
    NSPrincipalClass = GHApplication;
    NSSupportsAutomaticGraphicsSwitching = 1;
}
    library:       Contents/Library/
    library items: LoginItems/GitHub Conduit.app/
    schemesList:   github-mac
    activityTypes: NOTIFICATION#VEKTX9H2N7:com.github.GitHub, pv-fb2923e44f3b4b
    --------------------------------------------------------
    claim   id:            11940
        name:          Directory
        rank:          Default
        roles:         Viewer  
        flags:         doc-type  
        icon:          
        bindings:      'fold'
    --------------------------------------------------------
    claim   id:            11944
        name:          com.github.GitHub
        rank:          Default
        roles:         Viewer  
        flags:         url-type  
        icon:          
        bindings:      github-mac:
--
    );
    CFBundleExecutable = "GitHub Desktop";
    CFBundleIconFile = "AppIcon-Release";
    CFBundleIdentifier = "com.github.GitHub";
    CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion = "6.0";
    CFBundleName = "GitHub Desktop";
    CFBundlePackageType = APPL;
    CFBundleShortVersionString = "Deer Types";
    CFBundleSignature = "????";
    CFBundleSupportedPlatforms =     (
        MacOSX
    );
    CFBundleURLTypes =     (
                {
            CFBundleURLName = "com.github.GitHub";
            CFBundleURLSchemes =             (
                "github-mac"
            );
        }
    );
    CFBundleVersion = 222;
    NSAppleScriptEnabled = YES;
    NSHumanReadableCopyright = "Copyright \U00a9 2016 GitHub, Inc.";
    NSMainNibFile = MainMenu;
    NSPrincipalClass = GHApplication;
    NSSupportsAutomaticGraphicsSwitching = 1;
}
    library:       Contents/Library/
    schemesList:   github-mac
    activityTypes: NOTIFICATION#VEKTX9H2N7:com.github.GitHub, pv-fb2923e44f3b4b
    --------------------------------------------------------
    claim   id:            33368
        name:          Directory
        rank:          Default
        roles:         Viewer  
        flags:         doc-type  
        icon:          
        bindings:      'fold'
    --------------------------------------------------------
    claim   id:            33372
        name:          com.github.GitHub
        rank:          Default
        roles:         Viewer  
        flags:         url-type  
        icon:          
        bindings:      github-mac:
--
    );
    CFBundleExecutable = "GitHub Desktop";
    CFBundleIconFile = "AppIcon-Release";
    CFBundleIdentifier = "com.github.GitHub";
    CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion = "6.0";
    CFBundleName = "GitHub Desktop";
    CFBundlePackageType = APPL;
    CFBundleShortVersionString = "Beset by Computers";
    CFBundleSignature = "????";
    CFBundleSupportedPlatforms =     (
        MacOSX
    );
    CFBundleURLTypes =     (
                {
            CFBundleURLName = "com.github.GitHub";
            CFBundleURLSchemes =             (
                "github-mac"
            );
        }
    );
    CFBundleVersion = 220;
    NSAppleScriptEnabled = YES;
    NSHumanReadableCopyright = "Copyright \U00a9 2015 GitHub, Inc.";
    NSMainNibFile = MainMenu;
    NSPrincipalClass = GHApplication;
    NSSupportsAutomaticGraphicsSwitching = 1;
}
    library:       Contents/Library/
    schemesList:   github-mac
    activityTypes: NOTIFICATION#VEKTX9H2N7:com.github.GitHub, pv-fb2923e44f3b4b
    --------------------------------------------------------
    claim   id:            34016
        name:          Directory
        rank:          Default
        roles:         Viewer  
        flags:         doc-type  
        icon:          
        bindings:      'fold'
    --------------------------------------------------------
    claim   id:            34020
        name:          com.github.GitHub
        rank:          Default
        roles:         Viewer  
        flags:         url-type  
        icon:          
        bindings:      github-mac:
--
            LSTypeIsPackage = 0;
        }
    );
    CFBundleExecutable = GitHub;
    CFBundleIconFile = "AppIcon-Release";
    CFBundleIdentifier = "com.github.GitHub";
    CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion = "6.0";
    CFBundleName = GitHub;
    CFBundlePackageType = APPL;
    CFBundleShortVersionString = "Troll The Respawn Jeremy";
    CFBundleSignature = "????";
    CFBundleURLTypes =     (
                {
            CFBundleURLName = "com.github.GitHub";
            CFBundleURLSchemes =             (
                "github-mac"
            );
        }
    );
    CFBundleVersion = 204;
    NSAppleScriptEnabled = YES;
    NSHumanReadableCopyright = "Copyright \U00a9 2015 GitHub, Inc.";
    NSMainNibFile = MainMenu;
    NSPrincipalClass = GHApplication;
    NSSupportsAutomaticGraphicsSwitching = 1;
}
    library:       Contents/Library/
    library items: LoginItems/GitHub Conduit.app/
    schemesList:   github-mac
    activityTypes: NOTIFICATION#VEKTX9H2N7:com.github.GitHub, pv-fb2923e44f3b4b
    --------------------------------------------------------
    claim   id:            34024
        name:          Directory
        rank:          Default
        roles:         Viewer  
        flags:         doc-type  
        icon:          
        bindings:      'fold'
    --------------------------------------------------------
    claim   id:            34028
        name:          com.github.GitHub
        rank:          Default
        roles:         Viewer  
        flags:         url-type  
        icon:          
        bindings:      github-mac:
--
                {
            CFBundleURLName = "SourceTree URL";
            CFBundleURLSchemes =             (
                sourcetree,
                "github-mac"
            );
        }
    );
    CFBundleVersion = "1.8.0.2";
    NSHumanReadableCopyright = "Copyright 2010-2013 Atlassian. All Rights Reserved.";
    NSMainNibFile = MainMenu;
    NSPrincipalClass = NSApplication;
    NSServices =     (
                {
            NSMenuItem =             {
                default = "Open in SourceTree";
            };
            NSMessage = openInSourceTree;
            NSRequiredContext =             {
                NSTextContent = FilePath;
            };
            NSSendTypes =             (
                NSFilenamesPboardType
            );
        }
    );
}
    library:       Contents/Library/
    schemesList:   github-mac, sourcetree
    activityTypes: pv-ce07118f141dd8, NOTIFICATION#:com.torusknot.SourceTreeNotMAS
    --------------------------------------------------------
    claim   id:            35152
        name:          Folders
        rank:          Default
        roles:         Viewer  
        flags:         doc-type  
        icon:          
        bindings:      'fold'
    --------------------------------------------------------
    claim   id:            35156
        name:          SourceTree URL
        rank:          Default
        roles:         Viewer  
        flags:         url-type  
        icon:          
        bindings:      sourcetree:, github-mac:
```

Comment: Usually it works like this: Clone & Download > Open in Desktop > GitHub Desktop.app opens and asks where to save the project folder (in my case ~/Development/GitHub/) and then the project is downloaded/synced inside Github Desktop.app. I think the *github-mac* binding isn't properly linked to your Github Desktop.app

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 1):

In this case it would seem that your browser is not recognising the URL to open the installed copy of GitHub Desktop. I just downloaded your repository into GitHub Desktop with no problem.

I would first run GitHub Desktop and make sure it is set up properly and you have installed the command line tools. If that doesn't fix the problem then I would try deleting the app and re-installing it.

The final possibility would be rebuilding the LaunchServices database using this command:

`/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user`